# Where does HealthKit read the default units?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8, healthkit

I would like to know where does the Health.app read the unit for the weight. Mine is always set to Kg but I'm not able to find an option to toggle this.
The HealthKit framework supports multiple units for weight: Kilogram, Gram, Ounce, Pound and Stone.

I'd like to know if there's an API to get the current Health.app weight unit so I can directly use that unit in my app too.

Any idea?

Comment: Hi Patrick!

I would like to retrieve the same data. What did you end doing? 
Were you checking the locale manually? Or used HealthKit API?

Answer (score 3):

Update: In the latest iOS 8.2 beta, there is a new API `-[HKHealthStore preferredUnitsForQuantityTypes:completion:]` that allows applications to access the user's preferred units for any `HKQuantityType` that the app is authorized to read or write.

The Health app uses different units for different types depending on the locale set for the device.  For instance in the United States pounds are used to display weight but in locales that use the metric system kilograms will be used instead.  Starting in iOS 8.2, the user may also specify a unit they prefer for many quantity types in the Health app.

Comment: That is unfortunate that apps cannot access to this direct API. 
Using HealthKit, seems like the user need to give authorization first. 
UX is not ideal to give an extra step just to figure if we need to display picker for pounds or kilograms.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to check user's locale and set the correct units manually.